# Problemas con integracion Django 3 y Vue 3

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack

Llevo dos dias intentando integrar Django 3 con Vue 3 y en parte lo he logrado pero no como quisiera.

Escenario. La idea es utilizar Vue 3 para los componentes que requieren Javascript y que no son importantes para el SEO como formularios de reservas, etc…

Realice la integración utilzando django-webpack-loader para inyectar el bundle en las plantilla de django.

Este es el archivo **vue.config.js**

```
const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");

module.exports = {
  publicPath: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/",
  outputDir: './dist/',

    pages: {
        main: {
            // entry for the page
      entry: 'src/main.js',
    }
    },

  chainWebpack: config => {

    config.optimization
      .splitChunks(false)

    config
      .plugin('BundleTracker')
      .use(BundleTracker, [{filename: './webpack-stats.json'}])

    config.resolve.alias
      .set('__STATIC__', 'public')

    config.devServer
      .public('http://0.0.0.0:8080')
      .host('0.0.0.0')
      .port(8080)
      .hotOnly(true)
      .watchOptions({poll: 1000})
      .https(false)
      .headers({"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["\*"]})
  }
};
```

Este es el contenido del **main.js** que es punto de entrada de la app de Vue3

```
import { createApp, reactive, ref } from 'vue'

const app = createApp({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  setup() {
  
    const data = {
      returned_task: ref(''),
      temp_task: ref(''),
      modify_index: ref(-1),
      tasks: reactive([]),
    }
    
    const methods = {
      select: (index) => {
        if (data.modify_index.value === index){
          data.modify_index.value = -1;
        } else {
          data.modify_index.value = index
          data.temp_task.value = data.tasks[data.modify_index.value]
        }
      },
      deleteSelected: () => {
        data.tasks.splice(data.modify_index.value, 1);
        data.modify_index.value = -1;
      },
      updateSelected: () => {
        data.tasks.splice(data.modify_index.value, 1, data.temp_task.value);
        data.modify_index.value = -1;
      }
    }
    
    // created lifecycle event is not needed  but let's mock a delay
    setTimeout(() => {
      data.tasks.splice(0, 0, ...['do this ‍', 'and that ']);
    }, 120);
    

    return {
      ...data,
      ...methods
    }
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

y esta en la plantilla html donde se debe renderizar Vue

```
<div id="app">
   [[modify_index]]
      <ul>
        <li v-for="task in tasks">[[task]]</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Lo que sucede es que no se renderiza nada dentro del div #app tampoco se muestgra ningún error y no podido encontrar muchas referencias en la web.

Gracias a quien me pueda tirar una mano.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado... El problema estaba en el archivo vue.config.js. Fue necesario añadir la opción runtimeCompiler: true, a la configuración.

He creado además un post sobre como [integrar Django 3 y Vue 3](https://www.codigojs.com/django-framework/integrar-django-3-con-vue-3/) en proyecto utilizando webpack para todo el que lo necesite

Espero pueda ser de utilidad.